# What is the sum $\sum_{n=n_0-N+l}^{n_0+N}1$?

Tags: summation

To be very concise, I am doing mechanics and, to my surprise,

$$\sum_{n=n_0-N+l}^{n_0+N}1 = 2N+1-l$$

Why is it so? Any help clarifying this would be very appreciated.

Comment: 'Can you do Addition?' the White Queen asked. 'What's one and one and one and one and one and one and one and one and one and one?'

Answer (score 3):

As the input of the summation is simply $1$ this effectively means that
$$\sum_{n=a}^b1=\overbrace{1+1+1+...+1+1+1}^{b-a+1 \text{ times}}=b-a+1$$
So in your example
$$\sum_{n=n_0-N+l}^{n_0+N}1=n_0+N-(n_0-N+l)+1=2N-l+1$$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying